# Bootstrap 3.0 : container-fluid adds horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap 3.0  and to add 100% container i use .container-fluid like this

```
.container-fluid{
width:100%; 
}
```

my html code is like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 ">
        <p  class="text-center" >
            Responsible for UI/ UX  Design Developement
        </p>
    </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

now when i use  container it works fine  but adding containef-fluid adds  horizontal  scroll . i used this  to remove horizontal screen

```
body { overflow-x: hidden !important; }
```

this style works in  desktops but not in mobile  how do i fix this issue please help

Comment: you need to share link of the website ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem. Why do you need to set container-fluid to 100%? I think its width should be 100% by default. If you want its content to fill out 100%, just remove its paddings.

Comment: i did so but there is bit of scroll in desktops and around 10px  on mobiles

Comment: @Sikander Can you post a plunkr or something with this behavior? I've tried to reproduce it but I'm getting no scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee anything without seeing an example, but I ran into a similar situation I believe and I ended up using this for my .container-fluid class :

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```